# JodaTime Setting TimeZone over Existing DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I would like to set a timezone over a constant DateTime.

1. I want to create a single DateTime in a certain timezone.
2. Set a new timezone to get a calculated DateTime object.

For example:

```
DateTime currentTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 23, 2, 0); // CONSTANT

// Looking for something that can perform this type of method.
currentTime.setTimeZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println("Asia/Tokyo Time" + currentTime);

currentTime.setTimeZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Montreal")
System.out.println("America/Montreal Time" + currentTime);
```

How would I be able to get this done using the Joda-time API.

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)

Comment: I've modified your sample code to make more sense - please check my changes, but I believe they're sensible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want "the same instant, just in a different time zone" then you want [`withZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)).

It's not `setZone`, because `DateTime` (like many types in Joda Time) is immutable. Instead, you use `withZone` and use the result. For example:

```
DateTime currentTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 23, 2, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime tokyo = currentTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println("Asia/Tokyo Time" + tokyo);
```

Output:

```
Asia/Tokyo Time2015-01-23T11:00:00.000+09:00
```

Note that if you *don't* specify the time zone when you construct a `DateTime`, it will use the system default time zone, which is rarely a good idea. (As noted in comments, if you're writing client code is may be that you *do* want the system default time zone - but I view it as best practice to state that explicitly, so that it's *really* clear to anyone who might consider using the code in a different context.)

Comment: What makes you say it's rarely a good idea to use the system default time zone?  Surely, in very many use cases, that's exactly what is required?

Comment: @David: almost never in server-side code - and where you *do* want it in client code, it's much clearer to specify that explicitly, to make it clear that it is a conscious decision.

Comment: Right, but there are very many Java applications that are just stand alone, not part of a client-server universe, and only ever operate within a single time zone.  In such applications, time zones are basically entirely irrelevant, and you will never want to do any date/time processing in anything other than the system default zone.  If I'm programming one of these, there seems to be little point in being explicit about time zones.  I don't entirely disagree with your point; I just think that "rarely" is a very strong word.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I would say it's useful to be explicit even in those cases (it's not hard to do - `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`) and it means that anyone looking at the code doesn't need to think "Were they writing this as part of a client app which only needs the system default or not?" Don't forget that code is often used (either directly or through copying) in new contexts.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, Jon.  I think I'm going to have to continue to disagree for now.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Fair enough - just remember the conversation the first time you end up *accidentally* using the default time zone, and it taking you a while to work out why. Bitter experience which is particularly painful in the UK, which is in UTC+0 for half the year...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your implementation, you want to make DateTime to behave like Calendar. Since Calendar is mutable, and DateTime is not, why not use the MutableDateTime - a mutable version of DateTime. See my code below:

```
    //this is the mutable version of DateTime, set to UTC as default
    MutableDateTime currentTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 23, 2, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC).toMutableDateTime(); // CONSTANT

    // Looking for something that can perform this type of method.
    currentTime.setZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Tokyo"));
    System.out.println("Asia/Tokyo Time : " + currentTime);

    currentTime.setZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Montreal"));
    System.out.println("America/Montreal Time : " + currentTime);

    //if you want to return a value in DateTime datatype
    currentTime.toDateTime();
```

I hope this one works for you. Cheer!